# Django combine two models instances into one instance for viewing

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am attempting to combine two different (but similar) model instances into one object to work with for viewing purposes. This is a very basic example of what I am trying to do (but for a more complicated model with many properties/functions):

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    amount = models.DecimalField(...)
    timestamp = ...

    @property
    def taxes()
         ...
         return tax_amount
```

Now say we have 2 purchases made by the same user. I want to combine those two instances so that in the user view it looks like there is only one instance, but it is really the sum of the two models. This includes the sum of model fields as well as any summable properties. I am not sure what would happen with functions on the model that aren't numerical (but I am okay if they just don't work for the combined instance).

Answer (score 0):

```
...
from django.db.models import Sum
From .models import Purchase
...

def get_total_purchase_amount(request, user_id):
    purchases = Purchase.objects.filter(user__pk=user_id).aggregate(Sum('amount'))
    print(purchases['amount__sum']
```

This is how you can achieve computations on querysets. Note the usage of `.aggregate()`. I strongly recommend that you go through Django docs on aggregation and annotations. Its available [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/). 
Keep in mind that `aggregate()` returns a dictionary object and not a query set.